# Django many to many field default

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to set the default value of many to many fields.

this is my models:

```
class Mess(models.Model):
    alias = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    admin = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='mess_admin'
    )
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        default=admin,
        related_name='mess_members'
    )
```

I am trying to make when there is not `members` filled, so the default member will be `admin`

for this, i set `default=admin` but it does not work, when i try to create a `mess` without filling `members` field from admin templates, yet it returns me erros: `This field is required.

Can anyone help me to set default value in manytomayfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`default` here stands for the default value in the whole table, thus is does not fits your need.
You should rather either use a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/), or a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtrigger.html) if using PostgreSQL , or override your `save` method, in order to update the `members` field after creation of an instance.

An other option is to check on retrieval: when you retrieve your instance, verify that `members` is not empty, if so, return `admin` instead of `members`.